# Problems accessing grunt live server (mac) from mobile device

Tags: terminal, gruntjs

The server works fine locally, but I can't access the server from outside when I'm entering the hostname in my mobile browser (webpage not available). I my Gruntfile.js i have

```
  connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: '130.236.124.57',
        livereload: 35729
      },//...
```

where hostname is the ip (inet) adress I get when I'm running `ifconfig` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your hostname to `0.0.0.0` to allow external requests and restart your grunt server.

Next, access your external server with your machine specific hostname/IP